# Linq with sum and group from two tables

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

Hi I have some two tables,

Product:

```
ProductID | IssueDate | Amount

1           2017-06-01  1000
2           2017-06-01  1000
3           2017-06-02  500
```

and Credit:

```
ProductID | Amount

1           500
1           500
2           1000
3           500
```

if I use query like this from SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.IssueDate, SUM(p.Amount), SUM(p.Total) 
FROM (SELECT p.IssueDate, SUM(p.Amount) AS Amount, 
(SELECT TOP 1 SUM(c.Amount) FROM Credit c WHERE p.Id = c.ProductId) AS Total from Product p
GROUP BY p.IssueDate, p.Id) p
GROUP BY p.IssueDate
```

I get this result:

```
IssueDate | Amount | Total

2017-06-01  2000     2000
2017-06-02  500      500
```

In C# Linq I can get this data by two queries like this:

```
var data = from p in Products.Collection
           select new
           {
              Product = p,
              Credits = Credit.Collection.Where(c => c.ProductID == p.ID).Sum(c => c.Amount)
           };

var result = from d in data
           group d by new
           {
               IssueDate = d.Product.IssueDate
           } into gr
           select new
           {
               IssueDate = gr.Key.IssueDate,
               Credits = gr.Sum(s => s.Credits),
               Total = gr.Sum(s => s.Product.Amount)
           };

var test = result.ToList();
```

Does anyone know a better (simpler) solution to get this result? Maybe in one query?

Comment: It's simple and readable for me. What is so complicated with current LINQ query?

Comment: I thought about efficiency, maybe in one query would be more performance.

Comment: LINQ generates SQL. Is it one query or many? How do they look like? Maybe it's already efficient? Maybe it is optimised and performs better than your SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Products.Collection.GroupBy(x => x.IssueDate)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                IssueDate = x.Key,
                Amount = x.Sum(p => p.Amount),
                Total = Credit.Collection.Where(c => x.Any(p => p.ProductID == c.ProductID)).Sum(c => c.Amount)
            }).ToList();
```